# How to get top 3 results in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get only the top 2 results using xslt. In the below input, it should get the difference of all `td[3]` and `td[4]` in each `tr`. finally, it should print only the top 3 value and top 2 value in the bottom.

Logic:

first  : 14-9=5

second  : 12-4=8

third  : 2-9=-7

fourth  : 3-7=-4

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>8</td>5
    <td>14</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Results should be:

```
<result>
  <top>
    <tp>8</tp>
    <tp>5</tp>
  </top>
  <bottom>
    <bt>-7</bt>
    <bt>-4</bt>
  </bottom>
</result>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:for-each select="table/tr">
     <xsl:variable name="market-price" select="./td[3]"/>
     <xsl:variable name="open-price" select="./td[4]"/>
     <xsl:variable name="price-difference" select="$market-price - $open-price"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have no idea how I can go further to fix this. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: @zx485 mate what is the unclear part?

Comment: Your result does not seem to match your input. There are only 3 rows, with difference values of 8, 5 and -7. Where did you get -4? Also you say top 3 and top 2 - which is it?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited the description. please sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could look at this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="tp" as="element(tp)+">
        <xsl:perform-sort>
            <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tr">
                <tp>
                    <xsl:value-of select="td[3] - td[4]"/>
                </tp>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <top>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$tp[position() le 2]"/>
        </top>
        <bottom>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$tp[position() ge last() - 1]"/>
        </bottom>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEvb/2